# Как назначить id программным путем?

Tags: java, android

Я динамически создаю в приложении программным способом кнопки. Как им присвоить свой уникальный id и обратиться к нему?

Comment: Имеет смысл добавить в вопрос код, в котором создаются кнопки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод `new View(this).setId(int)`

**UPD** Могут возникнуть трудности с входным параметром, т.к. обычное число не допускается, а статический метод `View.generateViewId()` доступен только для API >= 17